# How to use drag cursors without drag events (custom drag and drop)

Tags: c#, .net, draggable

I'm making my own draggable controls similar to tabs in Visual Studio. Default system drag and drop cannot achieve the effect, so I just handle control's MouseDown, MouseMove and MouseUp events. The effect works as charm, but it would be perfect if I could change the cursor while dragging the control, but it is NOT windows drag drop operation. I don't have DragEffect available.

Is it completely impossible?

BTW, I don't use windows drag and drop because I need my control to be dropped both on another display's desktop area or another control of my application. Try to drag Visual Studio tab to see the effect. Mine works exactly the same. I mean while dragging Visual Studio tab the cursor doesn't change. I repeat the question: is it impossible to change it to a drag cursor?

I just need system drag cursors data and set system cursor to one of them. I suppose it could be done via pinvoke somehow, but it beats me how. I don't want to set external bitmap as cursor, it has to be real, original drag cursor. It's a challenge :)

Comment: You can steal the cursors out of c:\windows\system32\ole32.dll.  It isn't legal.  Drawing them yourself isn't exactly difficult either, they are simple designs.

Comment: When I directly link to a DLL it's probably legal, that's what Dynamic Linked Libraries are for. Thanks, I'll follow this hint. So I'll try to get cursor resource from ole32.dll and set this as custom cursor while dragging. Should work, I guess.